# While loop heavy on CPU

Tags: c, linux, infinite-loop

I have this code:

```
int _break=0;
while(_break==0) {

    if(someCondition) {
        //...
        if(someOtherCondition)_break=1;//exit the loop
        //...
    }

}
```

The problem is that if `someCondition` is `false`, the loop gets heavy on the CPU. Is there a way to sleep for some milliseconds in the loop so that the cpu will not have a huge load?

**Update**

What I'm trying to do is a server-client application, without using sockets, just using shared memory, semaphores and system calls. I'm doing this on linux.

`someOtherCondition` becomes true when the applications receives the "kill" signal, while `someCondition` is true if the message received is valid. If it's not valid, it keeps waiting for a valid message and the while loop becomes a heavy infinite loop (it works but loads the CPU too much). I would like to make it lightweight.

I'm working on Linux (Debian 7).

Comment: What are you actually trying to wait for? What is `someOtherCondition` and how does it change? Also, what operating system or threading library (if you're using threading) are you using?

Comment: You mean, like `usleep` or `nanosleep`?

Comment: On Win32 you can use the Sleep function.

Comment: There is no portable way to do this in C. What os are you using ?

Comment: This seems like an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have something you need to do, and you think this loop is the right way to do it, so you ask how to do the loop correctly. But it's very unlikely this is the right solution to your actual problem, whatever it is. To me, your question reads like, "How do I wait for something? And I'm not going to tell you what I'm waiting for."

Comment: Generally speaking, just sleeping is a bad idea in that you'll still be using more CPU than necessary, the wake-ups caused may be significant for power usage on battery-powered devices, and you won't react as quickly as possible to the condition changing. If possible, you should be waiting for the exact event instead, but as already pointed out, doing that requires knowledge of what you're doing and the platform you're running on.

Comment: Please try to mention clearly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz This program is kind of a server which waits for receiving messages from a client (no socket programming, i'm using system calls and shared memory/semaphore pool) this while terminates when the received message is "kill", but when `someCondition==false` it turns to an infinite loop and is heavy on CPU

Comment: Then you can possibly have the main thread sleeping, waiting for the external event to occur. How to do this is system-specific.

Comment: @Lundin Is it possible to do so with Linux-specific system calls?

Comment: @GimmyYang No idea. Why don't you edit your question, ask how to solve your specific problem on the Linux OS, add a Linux tag. As the question stands now, it is far too broad and might get closed because of it.

Comment: So your real question is: How can one process tell another cooperating process that there is data that it needs to process (in shared memory)? And how can the receiving process wait for that indication? (If Linux-specific is okay, the only operations you need are "wait" and "wake", so you can use a [futex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex).)

Comment: Read [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) and perhaps [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) & [eventfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a single-threaded application, then it won't make any difference whether you suspend the execution or not.

If you have multiple threads running, then you should use a binary semaphore instead of polling a global variable.

This thread should acquire the semaphore at the beginning of each iteration, and one of the other threads should release the semaphore whenever you wish this thread to run.

This method is also known as "consumer-producer".

**When a thread attempts to acquire a binary semaphore:**

- If the semaphore is released, then the calling thread acquires it and continues the execution.
- If the semaphore is already acquired, then the calling thread "asks" the OS to block itself, and the OS will unblock it as soon as some other thread releases the semaphore.

The entire procedure is "atomic", i.e., no context-switch between threads can take place while the semaphore code is executed. This is generally achieved by disabling the interrupts. Everything is implemented within the semaphore code, so you need not "worry" about it.

Since you did not specify what OS you're using, I cannot provide any technical details (i.e., code)...

### UPDATE:

If you are trying to protect a critical section inside the loop (i.e., if you are accessing some other global variable, which is also being accessed by other threads, and at least one of those threads is changing that global variable), then you should use a Mutex instead of a binary semaphore.

There are two advantages for using a Mutex in this case:

1. It can be released **only** by the thread which has acquired it (thus ensuring mutual exclusion).
2. It can resolve a specific type of deadlocks that occur when a high-priority thread is waiting for a low-priority thread to complete, while a medium-priority thread is preventing the low-priority thread from completing (a.k.a. priority-inversion).

Of  course, a Mutex is required **only** if you really need to ensure mutual exclusion for accessing the data.

### UPDATE #2:

**Now that you've added some specific details on your system, here is the general scheme:**

Step #1 - Before starting your threads:

```
// Declare a global variable 'sem'
// Initialize the global variable 'sem' with 'count = 0' (i.e., as acquired)
```

Step #2 - In this thread:

```
// Declare the global variable 'sem' as 'extern'
while(1)
{
    semget(&sem);
    //...
}
```

Step #3 - In the Rx ISR:

```
// Declare the global variable 'sem' as 'extern'
semset(&sem);
```

Comment: This program is kind of a server which waits for receiving messages from a client (no socket programming, i'm using system calls and shared memory/semaphore pool) this while terminates when the received message is "kill", but when someCondition==false it turns to an infinite loop and is heavy on CPU

Comment: So create a global semaphore, unlock it in the ISR (interrupt service routine) of the Rx interrupt, change your `while` to `while(1)` and pend on the semaphore at the beginning of the `while`.

Comment: I don't know what OS you're using, but in general, every Semaphore API should include a `set/get` interface: `SemaphoreSet` unlocks the semaphore; `SemaphoreGet` locks the semaphore and continues execution if the semaphore is unlocked, or blocks the calling thread if the semaphore is already locked.

Comment: I'm using Linux (precisely, Debian 7, but my code should run on all Linux-based platforms)

Comment: I'm using semget/semop for semaphores

Comment: Please see revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Spinning a loop without any delay will use a fair amount of CPU, a small time delay will reduce that you're right.

Using Sleep() is the easiest way, in Windows this is in the windows.h header.

Having said that, the most elegant solution would be to thread your code so that the code is only ever run when your condition is true, that way it will truly sleep until you wake it up.

I suggest you look into pthread and mutex.  This will allow you to sleep that loop of yours entirely until the condition becomes true.

Hope that helps in some way :)